# Content Search Webpart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, search, content

I have a very odd behavior of SharePoint 2013 out of the box Content Search Web part. It doesn't return any results at all. Every kind of query returns  zero results.

There is quite a lot of data and I'm also able through normal SharePoint search to retrieve results but not through the query of the Content Web part.

Could it be a configuration issue of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error on the screen? Probably a consideration of index reset in Central Admin, and run a full crawl.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you for your reply. I don't see any errors at all. but what I've found is that out of box Key language User.Name, which retrieves the current user information dosn't work properly. The User profile service is not running... could that be the issue for the out of box User.Name ?

Comment: I think that User Profile Service shall be at its running status. Start it in Central Admin. And also take at look the Forefront Identity Manager Service in windows service, make sure that is running.